# laravel Auth::login login not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Here is my code I am trying to login but its not working, data comes till before but something wrong in -> `Auth::login($user1);`
though if I put  `Auth::login($user1);` in if() condition it goes inside but not redirect in if condition,

```
if(count($staff) > 0)
{
  $staff['0']['type']='staff';
  $staff['0']['name']=$staff['0']['emp_name'];

  unset($staff['0']['emp_name']);
  Session::put('user',$staff['0']);

  $id= $staff[0]['id'];

  $user1 = Staff::find($id);
  //print_r($user);exit;
  //return Auth::login($user);
  Auth::login($user1);

  return redirect()->intended('/student');
}
```

Comment: You should use something like 
`if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Login failed.');
        }`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: sorry not working,it returns 2 even if  email ,passoword is right. 
   
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $password]   ))
 {
  return 1;
}else
 {
  return 2;
}

Comment: How did you signed up the user?

The length of password field in database should be 255 and while signing up the user you should used `bcrypt($data['password'])` to save the password in database.

Comment: how can reverse bcrypt ot match password?

Comment: You don't need to ,do that Auth::attempt will do that. One more thing that It is one way process , It means you can get plain password .